# Weird query result

Tags: mysql

I got the following table :

[image]

And i need to get the earliest time, per user, per date out of my database. So i have the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM `taskdate_user` WHERE `taskdate_time` IN
(
    SELECT min(`taskdate_time`)
    FROM `taskdate_user`
    WHERE `taskdate_time` BETWEEN '2013-01-21' AND '2013-01-28'
    GROUP BY  date_format(taskdate_time, "%Y-%m-%d"), user_id
)
ORDER BY `taskdate_time` ASC
```

Which results in :

[image]

Why does it return double '2013-01-21'? And it goes well with the other dates.

The database i'm using is :

> MySQL version: 5.1.66-0ubuntu0.10.04.3 through PHP extension MySQLi

Comment: you group by userid. Hence, while there are 2 different user id's found, it will divide it up into 2 records.

Comment: I think i was staring to it for too long, but the query result is correct.

Comment: Tuh tuh tuh, look beter next time Jack :p

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping also by user_id, and as a result, you have 2 entries for that date

Comment: Yes, thank you, i just saw it after blindly staring at the timestamp.